# How to select max Timestamp and min Timestamp of every Interval

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

[image]

I will use mysql or postgresql.

Is possible to select max and min timestamp of every interval by section2?

ex:

```
red block:2018-05-27 15:11:49~2018-05-27 15:11:54
green block:2018-05-27 15:11:55~2018-05-27 15:12:12
yellow block:2018-05-27 15:12:13~2018-05-27 15:12:16
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  I strongly suggest Postgres.  It is readily solved using the difference of row numbers:

```
select section1, section2, min(datetime), max(datetime)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by section1 order by datetime) as seqnum_1,
             row_number() over (partition by section1, section2 order by datetime) as seqnum_12
      from t
     ) t
group by (seqnum_1 - seqnum_12);
```

The difference of row numbers identifies the sections you are interested in.  The reason is a little hard to explain, but if you run the subquery, you can see what is happening -- the difference is constant for each section of interest.

The same code will work in MySQL 8.0.  However, earlier versions of MySQL do not support window functions, so the calculation is much more arduous.

Comment: May you explain what seqnum_1 - seqnum_12 mean, please ?

Comment: That is the difference between two values, `seqnum_1` and `seqnum_12`.